# PayPal PHP API, credit card and debit card get processed the same?

Tags: php, laravel, api, paypal, sdk

I am using the PayPal PHP API within a Laravel 5 install. It works great, and I am taking payments perfectly in the sandbox environment.

I am wanting to process both **credit** and **debit** cards.

I am really finding it hard to find anything online regarding if there is any different call for debit cards, the below code seems to work for all my test sandbox test cards.

Does anybody know if there is another call for processing debit cards?

```
$payer->setPaymentMethod('credit_card')
```

Massive thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the type of card (Visa, MasterCard, Amex, etc..) is supported by the processor, the transaction will be processed regardless of the fund source associated with the card. Debit, credit and prepaid describe the type of funds attached to the card but do not change how the card is handled by the merchant.

Comment: Thanks very much! that is great!